# I am trying to sum a range based on a conditional formatting - bold in this case

Tags: conditional-statements, sum, formatting, bold

I have VBA code that works if the cell is actually bold but it does not work if bold via conditional formatting. This code sums if the cell is actually bold:

```vb
Function SumIfNotBold(MyRange As Range) As Double
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In MyRange
        If cell.Font.Bold = False Then
            SumIfNotBold = SumIfNotBold + cell
        End If
    Next cell
End Function
```

Can this be modified to handle cells that are formatted conditionally.

I tried finding vb code that looked for conditional formatting bold and summed a range only if it was not bold.